# automatic traffic light animation

Tags: javascript

I built a script that loops through the lights in a traffic light automatically in a constant rate. however, I want to make the lights change at different time intervals to make it as realistic as possible.

this is the traffic light script:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
     <head>
     <title>Traffic lights system</title> 
  </head>
<body bgcolor="#5106A5">
<h1 style="text-align:center;font-family:verdana">Traffic light</h1> 
<div style="text-align:center">
<img alt="Traffic Light" id="TrafficLight" src="red.jpg"></img>
</div> 
<div style="text-align:center">
<button class="button" onclick="changeImage()">Change light</button> 
<button class="button" onclick="automatic()">Automatic lights</button> 
<button class="button" onclick="pauseAutomation()">Stop automation</button>
</div>
 <script>
var TrafficLightCase = ["red.jpg", 'yellownred.jpg', 'green.jpg', 'yellow.jpg'];
var TrafficLightPosition = 0;
 function changeImage() { 
 TrafficLightPosition++;
     if (TrafficLightPosition == 4) {
  TrafficLightPosition = 0;
}
document.getElementById('TrafficLight').src = TrafficLightCase[TrafficLightPosition];
}
function automatic() {
    time_interval = setInterval(changeImage, 1000);
} 
function pauseAutomation() {
    clearInterval(time_interval);
}
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only 4 cases for lights. You can use different functions for each case with different intervals for simplest solution.

Comment: can you show me the code that is required to do that